# Published BizTalk Service. How can it return parameters to calling app?

Tags: web-services, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an MVC Web App that calls a BizTalk WCF Service (generated by the BizTalk WCF Publishing Wizard). It is expected that after passing parameters to this Service, a return value is obtained from the BizTalk orchestration.

My question is that how do I create an orchestration that can return parameters to the calling MVC Web App?

Any example or tutorial here will do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you will be able to do this with orchestration.

I think this is a similar question - [BizTalk web service to return a value rather than void + ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627798/biztalk-web-service-to-return-a-value-rather-than-void-ref)

CodeProject [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462628/BizTalk-Server-WCF-Custom-Service-Behaviour)